# how we can use customized google calendar offline

Tags: html, scala, playframework-2.0, google-calendar-api

I want to embed google calendar in my website .

i am using this time following code :

```
<iframe src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?title=dash"></iframe>
```

It is loading from the web. but i want it should load from my local directory on server.

Comment: "it should load from my local directory on server." That doesn't make any sense. Google Calendar is an internet/web accessed application. Please add more detail on what you're trying to do.

Comment: i want to run my application on localhost only..... which dont have internet connection.

Comment: Them you can't embed Google Calendar. What is the eventual aim of what you are looking to do?

Comment: i am workin on my personal project ....that will run on 2-3 client ....and it will not be connected to the internet ... the goal of this project is to schedule my work on calendar

Comment: Then you can't use Google Calendar, then, which is, as far as I know, an internet-hosted service from Google. You'll need some local calendar server

Comment: okey...thanks. i have decided to create my own calendar